# How do I show the amount of time it takes for EXTJS to load my datagrid?

Tags: extjs

I want to do some speed tests in Ext JS 6.2 on my datagrid component to see how long it takes in seconds for my application to load a datagrid that has 25,000 rows in it.

Is there a configuration option I can turn on to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var timeToLoad = function(grid) {
    var store = grid.getStore();

    console.time('test');
    store.load({
         callback: function() {
             console.timeEnd('test');
         }
    });
}

timeToLoad(grid);
```

Check this fiddle for a full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ijl

Comment: Okay, would I do this in my the Grid or Store for my App?

Comment: You can use this wherever you want. You could place the call to timeToLoad(grid) inside a button handler, as long as you have the correct grid reference.

Comment: Would this work? `initComponent: function() {
        console.log("Init Component");

        var store = this.grid.getStore();

        console.time('test');
        store.load({
            callback: function() {
                console.timeEnd('test');
            }
        });

        this.callParent();
    }`

Comment: I added a fiddle to the example on how you should use this.

Comment: I've not gotten it to work yet exactly, but I think it has more to do with my Code then anything else.

Comment: Well, just make sure you start the timer before you load the store and end the timer inside the store load callback and it should work.